# How to check running output for a process which is not being explicitly logged?

Tags: logs, services, journalctl

One of our machines is running geth ( ethereum blockchain client )

ideally, to check the program output, we will have something like this;

```
geth --datadir ./myDataDir --networkid 1114 console 2>> myEth.log
```

However, what if we forget to redirect the log of the process to a file ?

is there any possible way to check the running output of the program ?

please note that i cannot stop the program or meddle directly with its running, as it is being used in important projects

I have to check the log of the program

please help

Answer (score 0):

That is in general not possible. Especially, the program (or the libc) can itself detect whether the stdout are actually file handles, and behave differently.

You could still possibly attach a debugger to the process and intercept the logging calls without significantly disrupting the process.

It's a bit unusual that you didn't start a daemon from a daemon-manager like systemd that automatically logs everything the daemon outputs, but that level of professionalism is a bit on par for the cryptocurrency community.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mr. Müller. To answer your reservations, this is not a 'cryptocurrency community'. We are doing analysis & research on cryptocurrencies and DLTs. I did not set up the original geth server, someone else did. I am merely trying to resolve a problem there.